# Using Sustainsys.saml2 behind an SSL offloading

Tags: sustainsys-saml2

I am attempting to get sustainsys.saml2 to operate behind an SSL load balancer with the SSL truncated at the load balancer. If I pass SSL requests into the app, it all works as expected. What I want to do is pass HTTP requests into the app, and have sustainsys create logon requests with SSL based consumer assertion urls.  Is this possible ?

Answer (score 1):

Solved this one fast, for those interested all you have to do is handle the GetPublicOrigin notification

Answer (score 1):

As you've found out you can use the `GetPublicOrigin` notification. But that is really meant for an advanced scenario when you want to alter this per request. For normal cases just setting the `SpOptions.PublicOrigin` property is easier.